# Where should I add that tag?

Tags: html, meta-tags, og-meta

While reading the source of a known popular blog, I found some tags in the head, and I added them to my blog after correcting info in them, So, the description and keywords in that are between  and  should be here or with the codes beneath or the ones beneath should get up, Here is the code --> [Hosted on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pCVNJ1GA)

Comment: Please post your the relevant HTML code (including the `<head>` section containing your `<meta>` tags) within the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid some of your question seems lost in translation to me; however, it seems that you want to know where (in the flow of a typical HTML document) a `meta` tag should go.
The answer: `meta` tags belong anywhere in the head section of the document; that is, between `<head>` and `</head>`. They usually go near the top (after the `title` tag and before CSS information), although that is not a requirement. They should be a direct child of the `head` tag.

Meta tags are used by many automatic indexers to provide more relevant search results by a search engine; however, most major search engines now rely sparingly on meta tag data because they can often be a source of spam.

The pastebin contains unique `b` tags, which appear to be some sort of pre-processing I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: That answer is enough for me, Thanks for help.